# Efficient way to upload images to s3 from android front end or nodejs backend?

Tags: android, node.js, amazon-s3

In my app, I am uploading the images to AWS S3, and the image's s3 urls is posting to my database after uploading the images to s3. It is taking long time to compress the images and upload them to s3 based on user network access. So user have to wait until the images are upload.

- How can I decrease the user waiting time?
- Can I do the compressing and uploading in background service? or Post the images from our backend NodeJS.
- What is the efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) from AWS S3. This will return you a link which can be used to directly upload your file to S3 without going through your server. For processing your file you can use AWS Lamda Functions so your server is not getting any overhead of processing files.

For example with NodeJS

```js
const url = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('putObject', {
    Bucket: 'YOUR_BUCKET',
    ContentType: 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE',
    ACL: 'public',
    Key: 'path/to/yourfile'
})
```

Above example will return you an URL which can be sent to the user, so the user can directly upload a file from the browser/android app to the S3 bucket.
You can simply do a PUT request to returned URL from your Android App.

**Note:** Change ACL according to your need, in the example file is publicly accessible

[NodeJS API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property)